# Making POSTMAN able to read JSON files at a specific directory

Tags: postman

I've been searching and searching but i did not find anything useful, i would like to implement some **automation** in POSTMAN.

I don't know if this is even possible but i would like to force POSTMAN to automatically *read* JSON files from a directory , i.e: file system or whatever. Do you get me?

Everytime that i want to execute anything on POSTMAN i have to open the COLLECTION, select the desired COLLECTION, click on RUNNER and then: choose the ENVIRONMENT, select the data file and finally: click on **Start Run**. I don't want to do it manually no more

Take a look at these questions:

> Is it possible to schedule a task on POSTMAN?
>
> Is it possible to read/reach files from file systems or something like
>   that?

A friend of mine told me that it was possible but i don't have the details and i want to do it.

Can you help me? I'm pretty lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can this using Newman to run the Collection. All the usage details and examples can be found here:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman

You can use the `-d` flag to specify a file path to the datafile, for the Collection to use. This would be the same as running the collection in the UI, this just brings it out to the command line.

Comment: Hi Danny, how are you?
I was looking for something like this: schedule a task, i don't know: read the datafile/s stored in a file system, once it is processed without errors wait for a new datafile but NEVER read the same file twice. Do you get me?

Comment: Use Newman as a library and script something like that in Javascript or try and do something with Jenkins. Basically, whatever it is, you're going to need Newman.